# Struct union in C#, get exception when new the struct

Tags: c#

My question is to new a union-struct, but get exception (about incorrect alignment) while running. Is there something wrong with my partial code? Any better method to solve without using "unsafe"?

```
enter code here

public struct SR_CONFIG
{
   public UInt32    dwRate;
   public int       bVAD;
   public UInt16    wSilenceStart;
   public UInt16    wSilenceEnd;
   public UInt16    wMaxLength;
}

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public struct CmdStruct_Union
{
   [FieldOffset(0)] public SR_CONFIG    SrParams;

   [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 32)]
   [FieldOffset(0)] public Byte[] rev;
}

CmdStruct_Union myStruct = new CmdStruct_Union(); // <----- get exception when running
```

Comment: Sorry. I just posted partial code, which mainly made exception.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can enable unsafe code in the project, then this solution works:

```cs
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Explicit)]
public unsafe struct CmdStruct_Union
{
    [FieldOffset(0)] public SR_CONFIG SrParams;

    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst = 16)]
    [FieldOffset(0)] public fixed byte rev[16];
}
```

Accessing to the rev items is same as in regular arrays in C# (but method must be also marked as "unsafe", like struct above). Remember that debugger will show you only the first element of fixed array.

More about fixed size buffers: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/unsafe-code-pointers/fixed-size-buffers

Comment: Thanks. It works, but must set "unsafe".